cannot import name 'wrappers' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers' in python 3.8
I'm a researcher trying to reproduce the results of a different research group and when running their published code. Specifically when training a deep neural network on the correct training data it shows me the following error, when switching epochs: "ERROR cannot import name 'wrappers' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers'". I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 and Pycharm 2023.3.4, running a Python3.8 interpreter. You can find the full interpreter settings as well as the requirements and the error message in the text files.
System Information
Hardware Information (VM):
- Hardware Model:                              innotek GmbH VirtualBox
- Memory:                                      22.6 GiB
- Processor:                                   12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12700 × 12
- Graphics:                                    Software Rendering
- Disk Capacity:                               536.9 GB

Software Information (VM):
- Firmware Version:                            VirtualBox
- OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 23.10
- OS Build:                                    (null)
- OS Type:                                     64-bit
- GNOME Version:                               45.2
- Windowing System:                            Wayland
- Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.5.0-21-generic

Virtual Box Version 7.0.14 r161095 (Qt5.15.2)

Information (HOST):
- Memory:                                      32 GiB
- Processor:                                   12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700   2.10 GHz
- Graphics:                                    NVIDIA RTX A4000
- Disk Capacity:                               1 TB
- OS Name:                                     Windows 11 Pro
- OS Version:                                  23H2
- OS Type:                                     64-bit

Error Message
ERROR cannot import name 'wrappers' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers' (/home/osboxes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/runner/experiment_runner/experiment_runner.py", line 114, in <module>
    exr.run()
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/runner/experiment_runner/experiment_runner.py", line 55, in run
    self.run_bootstrapping()
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/runner/experiment_runner/experiment_runner.py", line 95, in run_bootstrapping
    bootstrapping(self.experiment_id, self.params['bootstrapping_n'], self.params['split_id'], self)
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/utils/experiments/validation.py", line 75, in bootstrapping
    runner.run_list_of_experiments(experiments)
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/runner/experiment_runner/experiment_runner.py", line 108, in run_list_of_experiments
    exr.run()
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/runner/experiment_runner/experiment_runner.py", line 45, in run
    self.run_single()
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/runner/experiment_runner/experiment_runner.py", line 83, in run_single
    my_object.train_model()
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/model/ecg_model_flex.py", line 165, in train_model
    self.model.fit(x=self.x_train,
  File "/home/osboxes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/utils/experiments/callbacks.py", line 60, in on_epoch_end
    visualize_model(self.model, self.main_experiment_logdir)
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/utils/experiments/model.py", line 73, in visualize_model
    plot_model(model,
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/utils/viz/model.py", line 298, in plot_model
    dot = model_to_dot(model,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/utils/viz/model.py", line 101, in model_to_dot
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import wrappers
ImportError: cannot import name 'wrappers' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers' (/home/osboxes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sf_shared/experiment-environment-ecg-ai-master/runner/experiment_runner/experiment_runner.py", line 119, in <module>
    raise Exception(e.args)
Exception: ("cannot import name 'wrappers' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers' (/home/osboxes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/__init__.py)",)

PyCharm Interpreter Settings (Python 3.8):
Keras-Preprocessing 1.1.2
Markdown    3.5.2
MarkupSafe  2.1.5
PyPDF2  1.26.0
PyWavelets  1.4.1
absl-py 2.1.0
astunparse  1.6.3
cachetools  4.2.4
certifi 2024.2.2
cffi    1.16.0
chardet 3.0.4
cycler  0.12.1
et-xmlfile  1.1.0
exceptiongroup  1.2.0
gast    0.3.3
google-auth 1.35.0
google-auth-oauthlib    0.4.6
google-pasta    0.2.0
grpcio  1.62.0
h5py    2.10.0
idna    2.1
imageio 2.34.0
importlib-metadata  7.0.1
iniconfig   2.0.0
jdcal   1.4.1
joblib  1.3.2
kiwisolver  1.4.5
llvmlite    0.41.1
matplotlib  3.3.0
natsort 7.1.0
networkx    3.1
numba   0.58.1
numpy   1.19.1
oauthlib    3.2.2
opencv-python   4.9.0.80
openpyxl    3.0.4
opt-einsum  3.3.0
packaging   23.2
pandas  1.0.5
pillow  10.2.0
pip 24
pluggy  1.4.0
protobuf    3.20.3
pyamg   4.0.0
pyasn1  0.5.1
pyasn1-modules  0.3.0
pybind11    2.11.1
pycparser   2.21
pycurl  7.43.0.5
pydot   1.4.1
pydotplus   2.0.2
pyparsing   3.1.1
pytest  8.0.2
python-dateutil 2.9.0.post0
pytz    2024.1
requests    2.24.0
requests-oauthlib   1.3.1
rsa 4.9
scikit-image    0.17.2
scikit-learn    0.23.1
scipy   1.10.1
seaborn 0.11.0
setuptools  56.0.0
six 1.16.0
soundfile   0.12.1
tensorboard 2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.1
tensorflow  2.2.2
tensorflow-estimator    2.2.0
termcolor   2.4.0
threadpoolctl   3.3.0
tifffile    2023.7.10
tomli   2.0.1
tqdm    4.49.0
tzdata  2024.1
umap-learn  0.4.6
urllib3 1.25.11
werkzeug    3.0.1
wfdb    4.1.2
wheel   0.42.0
wrapt   1.16.0
xlrd    1.2.0
xlwt    1.3.0
zipp    3.17.0

**
Requirements:**
pycurl==7.43.0.5
requests==2.24.0
matplotlib==3.3.0
numpy==1.19.1
scikit-learn==0.23.1
wfdb==3.0.1
pandas==1.0.5
xlwt==1.3.0
openpyxl==3.0.4
pydot==1.4.1
pydotplus==2.0.2
tensorflow==2.2.2
tensorboard==2.2.2
xlrd==1.2.0
tqdm==4.49.0
umap-learn==0.4.6
seaborn==0.11.0
scikit-image==0.17.2
pyamg==4.0.0
opencv-python==4.0.0.21
PyPDF2==1.26.0
natsort==7.1.0

As far as I know, the wrappers function has been moved to tensorflow.keras.utils in newer versions of TensorFlow. However, since I'm using version 2.2.2, that shouldn't be the issue if I'm not mistaken. As I'm trying to reproduce results from other researchers, my goal is to make the fewest changes possible to the code, so upgrading to newer Python versions and rewriting the code isn't an option. I'm certain that I'm doing something wrong with the packages/interpreter or something else, but can't seem to figure it out. I have now invested a plethora of hours into this. Is anyone here able to help me?
Thanks for taking the time to read this, and I'm looking forward to your replies.

PyCharm is using the wrong python environment. From the error message I can see that it tries to import from py3.11 /home/osboxes/.local/lib/python3.11/....
